# Get last ID after SQL insert

Tags: php, mysql

This code below inserts some data into a MySQL database. I want the page to load to this record after the insert but the variable ($insert) that I'm trying to load is not coming through on the header. can someone help?

```
           $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO riders (firstname,secondname,email,mobile,landline,dob,addressline1,town,county,postcode) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($firstname,$secondname,$email,$mobile,$landline,$dob,$streetaddress,$town,$county,$postcode));        
        $insert = mysql_insert_id();
        Database::disconnect();
        header("Location:read.php?id=.$insert");
```

Comment: mysql_ functions are deprecated in PHP, and would not work in combination with PDO anyways. Use the correct PDO function for the last insert ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$pdo->lastInsertId()` for getting last ID after SQL insert.